# Issue in OpenFaas Arkade install

Tags: kubernetes, openfaas

I tried to install OpenFaas CE on Kubernetes using the command

```
arkade install openfaas
```

but I get this error:

```
Release "openfaas" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: Unable to continue with install: CustomResourceDefinition "profiles.openfaas.com" in namespace "" exists and cannot be 
imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; 
label validation error: missing key "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": must be 
set to "Helm"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-name": must be set to "openfaas"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": must be set to "openfaas"

Error: exit code 1, stderr: Error: Unable to continue with install: CustomResourceDefinition "profiles.openfaas.com" in namespace "" exists and 
cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; label validation error: missing key "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": must be set to "Helm"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-name": must be set to "openfaas"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": must be set to "openfaas"
```

Someone know what can be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading through the error message, it seems like there is an issue with an existing CRD with the same name as ‘[profiles.openfaas.com](http://profiles.openfaas.com)’ in the cluster. In addition, it may also have a mismatch in the ownership metadata in Helm that you might want to double check. After checking, you may want to attempt to reinstall and see if issues persist. For more information and troubleshooting guide, I attached a documentation for openfaas.[1]

[1] https://docs.openfaas.com/deployment/troubleshooting/